# cannot implicitly convert type bool to unity Engine Animator PlayerPrefs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
cannot implicitly convert  type bool  to unity Engine Animator
```

so I'm trying to one of my animations with player prefab but I keep getting this error

```
shopm.light1 = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("animation") == 2;
```

I tried doing this as well but I get the same error message

```
shopm.light1 = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("animation", shopm.light1 ? 1 : 0);
```

Comment: shopm.light1.enabled = boolValue;

Comment: I'm confused on what you mean here  because I need to save this into the player playerprefs if I just made the shop.light1.enabled = boolvalue true or false then if I load the game wouldn't it just keep that same value>?

Comment: Error code suggests that shopm.light1 is an Animator and looking at your code, you are likely trying to enable or disable that Animator depending on GetInt's value. My suggested code will do just that. It isn't related to how the PlayerPrefs is handled.

Comment: You can create a public bool value true or false for example when you start the game if it's false `shopm.light1` is not enabled when the user triggers something you can set it true  from the script and control it's enabled or not

Comment: It would help to add more context .. in particular the types of your fields .. currently this question is not answerable

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more data in order to get a complete answer, but based on your code, I assume that *shopm* is an animator and *light1* is a parameter, so check this out and see if it helps:

```
shopm.SetBool("light1", PlayerPrefs.GetInt("animation") == 2);
```